# how can i get data of a specific id from backend in react js?

Tags: reactjs, axios, formik

I am trying to get a specific id related data from backend instead of whole database and then comparing the id. i am passing id using state param. I am new to react so it will helpful to explain as simply as you can.

this is my service for getting data

```
import http from "./http";
const getBoxes = () => {
    return http
      .get("/box/getAllBox")
      .then((result) =>
      result.data.content.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, key: index }))
    );
};
```

Comment: What does the structure of the response from your API call look like? We can't help you if we don't know things like this.

Comment: I have added an example to my code if /getAllBox endpoint returns an array of objects which each contains an ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do that by using the `filter()` property

For example

```
import http from "./http";
const getBoxes = () => {
    return http
      .get("/box/getAllBox")
      .then(result=>{
      result.data.content.filter(item=> item.id=="your ID")
      })
      .then((result) =>
      result.data.content.map((item, index) => ({ ...item, key: index }))
    );
};
```

Replace `your ID` with your custom id

Answer (score 0):

You should create a backend endpoint (if possible) where you can get one box. EG /box/{id}.

This means when you get this endpoint in react you can do result.data.{some property from the returning object} eg result.data.boxName

If you don't have the ability to change the backend, you could get the specific id from the array of boxes by looping through the results and finding where ID of the returned object matches the ID you're looking for - this requires the array of objects being returned to each contain an ID field.

```
import http from "./http";
const getBoxes = () => {
    return http
      .get("/box/getAllBox")
      .then((result) =>
          let itemFromID;

          for(let i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
              let item = result.data[i];
              if(item.id === 1) {
                  itemFromID = item;
                  break;
              }
          }
        // now you have the item in itemFromID variable
        console.log(itemFromID);
    );
};
```